# How to access HTTP service by typing IP address in Firefox?

Tags: services, ip, https

[image]

[image]

My ip is 192.168.142.128. But I can't access it.
I'm running Ubuntu in Virtualbox.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you running a https web server on your computer at 192.168.142.128? What has this question got to do with the https server at 192.168.127.132?

Comment: Yes, 192.168.142.128 is my ip. And 192.168.127.132 is from an example.

Comment: And you are running a web server with HTTPS on your computer? Have you tried accessing via 127.0.0.1, your local loopback interface?

Comment: @Doug Yes, and 127.0.0.1 doesn't work.

Comment: O.K., well now we need to know the version of Ubuntu you are using, as things have been changing. also which web server program. Try `$ sudo ss -tulpn | grep :443`. I get `tcp   LISTEN 0      511                0.0.0.0:443       0.0.0.0:*    users:(("apache2" ...` so apache is listening for any ip address on port 443.

Comment: It doesn't return anything. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Then it seems you are not running a web server servicing HTTPS on port 443. Therefore the results you get when trying to connect are correct and expected.